# Iterative fibonacci complexity, cannot undersant why it is O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, fibonacci

Please don't confuse the question with recursive fibonacci, which has the complexity 2^n.

This is the fibonacci iterative code i use :

```
def f(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
```

I tried to find the complexity and i got it T(n) = n * 4  + 4 = 4n + 4, but the graph that i got is no linear at all and is more of a n^2. For example:

```
print(timerf(250000)/timerf(50000))
```

This gives me result around 25.

I plotted a figure:

[image]

This shows that the fibonacci iterative method should be with complexity n^2. How to explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterative method complexity is `O(n)*cost_of_addition`

Usually people assume `cost_of_addition` to be a constant, but in case of Fibonacci numbers we quickly outgrow this assumption.

Since `F(n)` grows exponentially, number of digits in it is `O(n)`. So the resulting complexity is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Okay now that i understand it , a new problem has arised, cost_of_addition, it has some kind of exponential function of n  right ? Because the Fibonacci numbers get bigger very fast, but the addition cost depends on the fibonacci number, not the n, how would you implement the cost of addition ? I mean do you take the higher bound of fibonacci numbers ( if it exists ) and say that fibonacci(n) is always less than that function, and that is the complexity then ?

Comment: Edit, Of course it is the Golden ratio to the power of n which is the upper bound for fibonacci(n) function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the reason is that addition of integers does not take constant time but linear - **O**(number of bits)